# Make all apache requests of any kind/uri show the same page

Tags: apache-2.2

For the coming up SOPA blackout, I plan to shut down all of my websites. I'm not sure how to do this though! How do I make every web request made on any of my pages redirect to the same file? Any idea?

Comment: Are you planning a full shutdown (as I am for my personal site)?  For sites where that's not feasible consider using the script from http://sopablackout.org/ (you can copy it locally if desired to avoid the risks inherent in calling a script from an external domain...)

Answer (score 5):

In the server or vhost context (if you use `.htaccess` or directory context, drop the leading slashes):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^/sopa\.html$ /sopa.html [R,L]
```

This'll send a redirect (302) response for every page to the `sopa.html` page.  Alternatively, you could return the `sopa.html` content for every request without redirecting, but I suspect this approach is better with regard to search engine reindexing.

Comment: Note that you should be certain whatever method you use issue a **`302`** redirect ("Found:" -- temporary), not a 301 (Moved.  Permanent.) to avoid upsetting search engines.  302 is the default in Apache (I believe all versions) but can be explicitly specified as `R=302` if you're paranoid.

Answer (score 0):

[Google do not recommend](https://plus.google.com/115984868678744352358/posts/Gas8vjZ5fmB) using 302 for such protest message or maintenance page as this might affect ranking.

Here is how I do 503 error pages which is human readable as well:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=503
Alias /stop-sopa /var/www/stop-sopa
ErrorDocument 503 /stop-sopa/index.html
RewriteRule !^s/stop-sopa$ /stop-sopa [L,R=503]
```